# Autosize container between two other containers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

***solved with an expanded widget that takes on a blue widget
THX***

I would like to know if there is a good way to add to a container an infinite size contained by two other containers so that each device can correctly display my page no matter the size in height of the device

On the image below an illustration of my question
The two red frames are containers with a defined height and I would like to know what to add for the container to the blue frame

HomePage

[image]

Here is my widget which contains my container which contains my patient list

```
class PatientList extends StatelessWidget {
  const PatientList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: kSecondcolor),
      height: 300,// Autosize to add
      width: size.width,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Patients patients = patientList[index];
          return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 10,
              ),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (() {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => InformationPatient(patients)));
                }),
                child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 8, bottom: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          patientList[index].name +
                              ' ' +
                              patientList[index].firstname,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: 3,
                          left: 5,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'ID #' + patientList[index].id.toString(),
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ));
        },
        itemCount: patientList.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can try wrapping the middle one (blue frame) in an `Expanded` widget.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I didn't even think about it :)

Comment: You can include your solution on answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hossein Yousefi mentioned , using `Expanded` will get available space, If you to know the available size, you can use `LayoutBuilder` on top of it.

```dart
return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
    return  Container(
      height: constraints.maxHeight,
```